# connection pooling in hibernate 3 and hibernate 4

Tags: hibernate, connection-pooling

i want to implement the connection pooling in hibernate 4. Also, I want to know the way to check that connection pooling is working fine. (using log etc.)

```
Given below is the code for connection pooling in hibernate 3
    <property name="connection.pool_size">10</property>
    <property name="statement_cache.size">50</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_size">10</property>
    <property name="c3p0.min_size">1</property>
    <property name="c3p0.timeout">60</property>
    <property name="c3p0.max_statements">50</property>
```

Comment: is there any diff. b/w hibernate 3 and hibernate 4 for connection pooling implementation and check method that connection pooling is wokring

Comment: am using hibernate 4 with c3 pool. it works just fine for me

Comment: You can activate logging in your hibernateUtil class as below    java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("org.hibernate").setLevel(Level.ALL); 
            java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.mchange.v2.c3p0").setLevel(Level.ALL);